# F2PY wrap procedure that uses derived types only internally

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

It is stated in a lot of places that F2PY does not "support derived types", however, it is unclear to me whether this means that either

- derived types may not be used as parameters to procedures wrapped by
  F2PY
- derived types may not even be used internally in procedures I want to wrap with F2PY

To my use case the first point is an inconvenience but the second rather a deal breaker.

As an example, consider this module that computes a vector sum:

```
module derived_types

implicit none
public :: point, add

type :: point
   real :: x
   real :: y
end type point

contains

type(point) function add(p1, p2)

type(point), intent(in) :: p1
type(point), intent(in) :: p2

add%x = p1%x + p2%x
add%y = p1%y + p2%y

end function add

end module derived_types


module expose

use derived_types, only: point, add
implicit none

contains

subroutine vector_sum(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

real, intent(in) ::  x1, y1, x2, y2
real, intent(out) :: x3, y3

type(point) :: p1, p2, p3

p1 = point(x1, y1)
p2 = point(x2, y2)

p3 = add(p1, p2)

x3 = p3%x
y3 = p3%y

end subroutine vector_sum

end module expose
```

Subroutine `vector_sum` shall be exposed to Python. The derived type `point` is not to be passed between Python and Fortran.

This works as plain Fortran program (with an appropriate program block added) but F2PY fails:

`f2py -c ff.f90 only: vector_sum`

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "untitled" sources
f2py options: ['only:', 'vector_sum', ':']
f2py:> /tmp/tmpjdq8b9dq/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/untitledmodule.c
creating /tmp/tmpjdq8b9dq/src.linux-x86_64-3.8
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'ff.f90' (format:free)
Line #7 in ff.f90:"type :: point "
    analyzeline: No name/args pattern found for line.
Post-processing...
    Block: untitled
            Block: derived_types
                Block: unknown_type
            Block: expose
                Block: vector_sum
            Block: run
Post-processing (stage 2)...
    Block: untitled
        Block: unknown_interface
            Block: derived_types
                Block: unknown_type
            Block: expose
                Block: vector_sum
            Block: run
Building modules...
    Building module "untitled"...
        Constructing F90 module support for "derived_types"...
          Variables: point add
getctype: No C-type found in "{'attrspec': ['public']}", assuming void.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/f2py/f90mod_rules.py", line 143, in buildhooks
    at = capi_maps.c2capi_map[ct]
KeyError: 'void'
```

Can such a thing be done using F2PY at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering, I figured it would probably be easiest to compile the code that defines all derived types into a static library first, i.e.:

`libff.f90` containing:

```
module derived_types

implicit none

public :: point, add

type :: point
   real :: x
   real :: y
end type point

contains

type(point) function add(p1, p2)

type(point), intent(in) :: p1
type(point), intent(in) :: p2

add%x = p1%x + p2%x
add%y = p1%y + p2%y

end function add

end module derived_types
```

Compile with `gfortran -free -c libff.f90` to produce `libff.o`.

Then the code that uses the derived types from the pre-compiled module can be compiled with F2PY when linking the library, i.e.:

`ff.f90` containing:

```
module expose

use derived_types, only: point, add
implicit none

contains

subroutine vector_sum(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

real, intent(in) ::  x1, y1, x2, y2
real, intent(out) :: x3, y3

type(point) :: p1, p2, p3

p1 = point(x1, y1)
p2 = point(x2, y2)

p3 = add(p1, p2)

x3 = p3%x
y3 = p3%y

end subroutine vector_sum

end module expose
```

After using F2PY to build the Python extention with `f2py -c ff.f90 libff.o -m ff`, we can import it in Python with `from ff.expose import vector_sum`.

Lesson learned: Put the definition of derived types into a pre-compiled library then compile only the code using these types with F2PY.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single procedure, define the derived type therein as well as using contained procedures.
This is a *quick and dirty approach* which will only suffice for smaller problems.

An example implementation follows

```
! file: a.f90
subroutine vector_sum(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
  real, intent(in)  :: x1, y1, x2, y2
  real, intent(out) :: x3, y3

  type point
    real :: x(2)
  end type

  type(point) :: p1, p2, p3

  p1%x = [x1, y1]
  p2%x = [x2, y2]

  p3 = add(p1, p2)

  x3 = p3%x(1)
  y3 = p3%x(2)

contains

  type(point) function add(p1, p2)
    type(point), intent(in) :: p1
    type(point), intent(in) :: p2

    add%x = p1%x + p2%x
  end function

end subroutine
```

Compilation

```sh
$ f2py -c a.f90 -m amod
```

Usage in python

```py
>>> import amod
>>> amod.vector_sum(1, 2, 3, 4)
(4.0, 6.0)
```

Comment: This works and answers the question (+1), but prevents the derived type to be shared between different subroutines.

Comment: You can pass objects between contained procedures. But this might be of limited use for larger projects...